# Import static js in components

Tags: reactjs, webpack

If I add a resource using the following in index.html, how can I import it in the components in react application.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/resource.js" />
```

Comment: Think you can import the same way how you would import othervise , as long as its available for runtime in the global window space.